# Swipe to refresh data using SwipeRefreshLayout in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

I want my layout to be refreshed when the app starts and the data should show in and when the user swipes the data should be updated and show new data if new data is available on the server.

The actual problem is that the data is not loading when the app is started. Rather it is happening only on swiping. How can I achieve that on opening the app the data is loaded first and then the data is updated on swiping?

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    FragmentFirstBinding binding;
    APIInterfaces interfaces;
    ArrayList<VideoModels> list = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(list,getContext());
        binding.myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2);
        binding.myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        interfaces = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofit().create(APIInterfaces.class);
        binding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(true);
        binding.swipeToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                interfaces.getPosts().enqueue(new Callback<List<VideoModels>>() {
                    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<VideoModels>> call, @NonNull Response<List<VideoModels>> response) {
                        list.clear();
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            assert response.body() != null;
                            list.addAll(response.body());
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            binding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<VideoModels>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Check you Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        binding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        binding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);

        return binding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

**EDIT-1: Added complete code.**

Your answer will helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding the solution for 1 day. Finally, I found my solution.

To use `SwipeRefreshLayout` work in `Fragment` and want to refresh your data `Onswipe`. use the below code and modify it as your requirement.

This is a `fragment`.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        // swiping on starting of an app.
        binding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(true);
        getData();
        binding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);

        // when user swipe
        binding.swipeToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                getData();
            }
        });
        return binding.getRoot();
    }
    public void getData(){
        // you have to put all of your onCreate code here to work properly. most of time it throws an error. So, make sure you added code properly.
        ArrayList<VideoModels> list = new ArrayList<>();
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(list,getContext());
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2);
        binding.myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        binding.myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        binding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(true);
        interfaces = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofit().create(APIInterfaces.class);
        interfaces.getPosts().enqueue(new Callback<List<VideoModels>>() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<VideoModels>> call, @NonNull Response<List<VideoModels>> response) {
                list.clear();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    assert response.body() != null;
                    list.addAll(response.body());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    binding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<VideoModels>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Check you Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                binding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call this method in onResume() state

```
  public void getData() {
            interfaces.getPosts().enqueue(new Callback<List<VideoModels>>() {
                @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<VideoModels>> call, @NonNull Response<List<VideoModels>> response) {
                    list.clear();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        assert response.body() != null;
                        list.addAll(response.body());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        binding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<VideoModels>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Check you Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    binding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: I tried this method, But this method has not solved my problem.

Comment: your answer is helpful but you have to put `getData` into `swipeToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener`

Answer (score 0):

if you call `binding.swipeLayout.isRefreshing = true` 
in SwipeRefreshLayout source code, `mNotify` boolean value is **false**
so cannot do anything in `setOnRefreshListener`

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if (mRefreshing) {
            // Make sure the progress view is fully visible
            mProgress.setAlpha(MAX_ALPHA);
            mProgress.start();
            if (mNotify) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onRefresh();
                }
            }
            mCurrentTargetOffsetTop = mCircleView.getTop();
        } else {
            reset();
        }
    }
```

this is why `setOnRefreshListener` not invoke
if you want manual invoke it do like this by reflect set  `mNotify` boolean value is **true**

```
val swipeClass = SwipeRefreshLayout::class.java
val method = swipeClass.getDeclaredMethod("setRefreshing", Boolean::class.java, Boolean::class.java)
method.isAccessible = true
method.invoke(binding.swipeLayout, true, true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't understand your code. Can you please explain your code?

Comment: update my answer, pls read and debug your code with source code, you will know everything